# Android - AssertionFailedError on startActivity method in ActivityUnitTestCase test class

Tags: android, unit-testing, assertion, start-activity, activityunittestcase

I am trying to test an activity in a module. I am just trying to start this activity in the test method, but I always have a `AssertionFailedError`. I searched the web for this issue but could not find any solution. Any help is appreciated.

This is my test class:

```
public class ContactActivityTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<ContactActivity> {

    public ContactActivityTest() {
        super(ContactActivity.class);
    }


    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }


    public void testWebViewHasNotSetBuiltInZoomControls() throws Exception {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),
                ContactActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent, null, null);
    }


    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
at android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase.startActivity(ActivityUnitTestCase.java:147)
at com.modilisim.android.contact.ContactActivityTest.testWebViewHasNotSetBuiltInZoomControls(ContactActivityTest.java:29)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1763)
```

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried with an empty activity or could it be that `ContactActivity` code is responsible for the error?

Comment: @Simas it might well be, the problem is which part of the code. I tried with an extension of either `FragmentActivity` and `Activity`, and I emptied the latter's code and it still crashed with the same issue.

Comment: I believe you need to have the startActivity(...) code in setUp()

Can you check this, and if so I'll add an answer for you to accept.

Comment: @MGranja That's the JUnit 3 that deals with calling the test method

Comment: @DougEdey According to the [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.Object%29) it should NOT be called in setUp() (because of a ClassLoader issue), but I tried anyway to call in eithersetUp or test method, with the same issue.

Comment: @Xcihnegn that's the line: `startActivity(intent, null, null);`

Comment: actually I saw one sample test codes that calls `startActivity` from `setup `, so could just put in setup without put in test method

Comment: Is the Activity defined in the manifest file? I tracked down the exception, and it ends up here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/app/Instrumentation.java?av=f#1763 (ActivityNotFoundException)

Comment: try to update java veraion from 1.6 or upgrade ane run again. May be it work. If upgrade then try to down grade try both.

Comment: @Vince are you seeing this exact error?

Answer (score 12):

ActivityUnitTestCase's **startActivity()** method needs to be called on the main thread only.

This can be done in the following ways:

1. Use the *@UiThreadTest* annotation before your test method:

   ```
   @UiThreadTest
   public void testWebViewHasNotSetBuiltInZoomControls() throws Exception {
       Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),
               ContactActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent, null, null);
   }
   ```
2. Use the **[runOnMainSync](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#runOnMainSync(java.lang.Runnable))** method of the Instrumentation class:

   ```
   public void testWebViewHasNotSetBuiltInZoomControls() throws Exception {
       final Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),
               ContactActivity.class);

       getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               startActivity(intent, null, null);
              }
           });
    }
   ```

[Why am I right?](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/AndroidJUnitRunnerUserGuide#Instrumentation_Thread_Handlers)

Comment: I'm sorry that I could not verify the answer to give you my initial bounty. But the annotation solved the issue, so here it is repaired, you deserved this bounty. Thanks!

Comment: This answer solves the issue, it would be great if the OP of question accepts this as answer.

Comment: You might want to extend `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` instead.