# Junit Test an Activity getting null pointer exceotion

Tags: android, junit

```
public class FitiquityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LoginActivity> {
    LoginActivity mActivity;
    private EditText username;
    private EditText password;
    public FitiquityTest()
    {
        super("com.packagename.LoginActivity",LoginActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mActivity = this.getActivity();
        username = (EditText) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.login_email_mobile_et);
        password = (EditText) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.login_password_et);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPreconditions() {
        assertNotNull(username);
        assertNotNull(password);
    }

    @Test
    public void testText() {
        assertEquals("hello",username.getText());
        assertEquals("hello123", password.getText());
    }

}
```

This is my Test class.I am trying to learn junit.I have an activity named login.I want to test on it.Now in the above class I am getting exception on setup method in mActivity = this.getActivity(); line.So my question is if I am not be able to start an activity so I will get a null pointer exception obviously.So how to start an Activity in junit test class.I have tried the following link answer 2 also.

[Android - AssertionFailedError on startActivity method in ActivityUnitTestCase test class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576932/android-assertionfailederror-on-startactivity-method-in-activityunittestcase-t)

//Now please help as I am new to Junit.

//I have added instrumentation tag in Manifest also.Lint is also disabaled.

```
<instrumentation
    android:targetPackage="com.fitiquity"
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />

    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
```

Comment: post your stack trace

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.fitiquity.FitiquityTest.setUp(FitiquityTest.java:31).getting this only

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in that line. Did you added the `instrumentation` meta data to manifest ?

Comment: No.Should i post the code for Manifest also?

Comment: what's the line 31 ?

Comment: Sorry. in which file??Java or Manifest?I have added instrumentation tag also

Comment: in java where the error was happened

Comment: in mActivity = this.getActivity(); line,this.getActivity() is returning null.

Comment: @Mainak are You sure You are running this tests as androidTest's not just plain junit Tests? Directories should be /androidTest(for Android) or /test(for JUnit)

Comment: @Axxxon.I have put the java class in plain junit test.Cause if I put the java files in androidTest then it is showing as red j symbol at the bottom.and in Build variants I have to select the unit test also.So if i am doing wrong please tell me what to do?